# PHP5: un-expected result "rtrim()"

Tags: php

I don't know if this is a PHP bug or what,

when I run:

```
    $query = "test text";
    $query = rtrim($query,'union all select ');
```

"$query" return (each time)

```
$query = 'test tex';
```

should be:

```
$query = 'test text';
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I have long script and require this, but by the way this is not the correct behavior of "rtrim()"

Comment: http://php.net/RTRIM - Explains it will remove specified characters from the end of the string.

Comment: what you should be looking at is `str_replace`

Comment: Hold on - the correct behavior isn't the one specified in the docs?  Where can I find an explanation of this `correct behavior`?

Comment: Before calling something a bug you need to make sure you are not mistaken about how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter to [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) is a list of all the characters that should be trimmed. Therefore, `rtrim("text", "union all select ")` will remove the last characters which are `u`, `n`, `i`, `o`, `n`, ..., `c`, or `t`.

Thus, if the text is `test text`, the above code will remove the last `t`, because it's part of the list of characters you told it to remove.

To remove the text `union all select` from the end of the input string, you could use something like:

```
$query = preg_replace('/union all select $/', '', $query);
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bug in PHP.  Check the docs for [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim):

> **character_mask** You can also specify the characters you want to strip,
>   by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters
>   that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of
>   characters.

The second parameter is what *individual characters* to remove.

Comment: how to replace the hole string?

Comment: @mwafi: You mean the "whole" string.  I'll edit the answer with a solution in a second.

Comment: @rid: Err... give me a sec.  I haven't had enough coffee today.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, hmm, you could check if the position returned by `strrpos()` + the number of characters in the search string is equal to the total number of characters in the input string.

Comment: @rid: There we go.  `strrpos()` finds if the string *ends with* it and where it starts.  `substr` will read from the beginning up until that point.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, wouldn't `strrpos()` find it even if the sting doesn't end with it? It just says it finds the last occurrence, not necessarily if that occurrence is also the last part of the string. For example, try adding some more characters at the end of `$query`.

Comment: @rid: Dammit.  You're right again.  Just use a regex!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the [correct result to me](http://php.net/RTRIM).

The second parameter 'union all select ' is a character mask, meaning that it's not treated as a string, but any of the characters found in the string will be trimmed from the first parameter, starting from the right end.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is taking off the 't' is because of what the character mask does. The rTrim takes 2 parameters, the string and a character mask. Any characters in the second parameter will be stripped from the right of the string specified. If you call rTrim without a character mask you should see expected results.